Issue in observing multiple divs with singleton ResizeObserver instance
I was working on a problem where I have 20 divs(div-0, div-1, etc.) and a ResizeObserver on the application level. Using a single instance of this ResizeObserver, I am observing on all the 20 divs. Also, the callback passed to the ResizeObserver prints the new dimension of the div observed.
Issue is, no matter which div I resizes, the callback gets triggered for first div only. Can someone help me finding resolution to this problem?
Here is what I wrote:
// ResizeObserver at the application level
class ResizeObserverUtility {
    static getInstance (callback) {
        if (typeof ResizeObserver === 'undefined') {
            console.warn('ResizeObserver is not supported by this browser.');
            return null;
        }

        if (!ResizeObserverUtility.instance) {
            console.log('Creating a new ResizeObserver instance');
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            ResizeObserverUtility.instance = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
                for (const entry of entries) {
               
                    const { height, width } = entry.contentRect;
                    callback(height, width);
                }
            });
        }
        return ResizeObserverUtility.instance;
    }
}

// inserting divs into the dom
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const dummyDiv = new DIV();
    document.getElementById(`div-${i}`).appendChild(dummyDiv);
}

// Here is how I use the instance in the DIV.js
// in the DIV constructor
const util = ResizeObserverUtility.getInstance((height, width) => this.exampleFunc(height, width));
util.observe(this._domNode); // here domeNode can be div-0, div-1, and so on.

I tried looing into the chrome console in the exampleFunc in which 'this' points to the 'div-0' only even when I resizes any other div.

Maybe you need to observe each of the elements?

@ITgoldman each element is being set to be observed when created through DIV.

I see now. Your ResizeObserverUtility is designed like a singleton, in the sense that it only returns the first instance that was created.

Yeah, I could figure it out. Thanks anyways.
